# What is the purpose of the Firefox preference "loop.oauth.google.redirect_uri"?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I just found that my installation of the Mozilla Firefox browser has the following preference:
"**loop.oauth.google.redirect_uri**"
which has a string value set to "**urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto**"

I searched the Internet but could not find anything definite about this preference other than that it is set by default.

**What is the purpose of this preference and is it safe to disable it?**

Comment: Go read the source code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a very late answer, but for historical purposes...

The word 'loop' refers to the now-defunct project [Loop, AKA Firefox Hello](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Loop), which was a short-lived project to allow easy communications from within the browser.

The 'oauth' part refers to the fact that project Loop allowed users to import contacts from other services, and one of them was via [Google using OAuth](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Loop/OAuth_Setup).

Google also has a page that details [how OAuth redirect_uri_path works](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp).

Hope that helps give you some closure. :)

Comment: I would elaborate more if I could, but I was not a developer of the Firefox Hello feature. I think the above links contain a lot of helpful technical info, though! I added an extra link that explains how redirect_uri_path works.